# makefile syntax error for if-else construct

Tags: shell-script, scripting, make

Hi I am stuck in this problem for long time. I expect output "ok" for this makefile. But I get syntax error on calling `make`:

> ifeq (0, 0)
>
> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
>
> make: *** [default] Error 2

Code:

```
CHK = 0

default:
    ifeq ($(CHK), 0)
        echo "ok"
    else
        echo "not ok"
    endif
```

Comment: This is not `make` syntax but rather a non-portable `gmake` extension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are Makefile directives, not shell directives, so they shouldn’t be tab-prefixed:

```make
CHK = 0

default:
ifeq ($(CHK), 0)
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
endif
```

Otherwise Make passes them to the shell, rather than handling them itself.